# Deflate Algorithm Pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, encoding, compression, pseudocode, deflate

I am currently trying to understand how DEFLATE algorithm works. I know that it is a combination of LZ77 and Huffman Coding. I've studied how those two work, but I currently have no idea how they are used or integrated in DEFLATE.

Is there a pseudocode of the DEFLATE algorithm? I have been searching for it but unfortunately, all I see are explanations and there is no exact algorithm / pseudocode for deflate.

Thank you very much for your help.

BTW, I already checked this sites: 
http://www.zlib.net/feldspar.html
http://www.gzip.org/algorithm.txt
I also checked the RFC 1951 documentation

For example, I have the string "DEFLATE INFLATE" 
how is it going to be compressed using DEFLATE?

Answer (score 4):

"DEFLATE INFLATE" is a very short string, and so will be encoded using the fixed Huffman codes.  A disassembly of the compressed data gives:

```
last
fixed
literal 'DEFLATE IN
match 5 8
end
```

which means a single fixed block which is the last block, the literal bytes "DEFLATE IN", and a string match eight bytes back for five bytes, which copies "FLATE".

The fixed Huffman codes encode the literal bytes and the match length and distance, as well as the end code that marks the end of the block.  The literal, length, and end codes are in one Huffman code.  If a length is decoded, then that is followed by a distance code from it's own Huffman code.

In addition to RFC 1951, which explains the deflate format completely and in detail, you can also look at the [`puff.c`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/contrib/puff/puff.c) code in the zlib distribution which is meant to document the deflate format unambiguously by virtue of being a simple, complete, and well-commented inflator.

You can also disassemble the results of deflate compression (e.g. using `gzip`) for more insight using [`infgen.c`](https://github.com/madler/infgen), which produced the example above.

You need to first understand the deflate format by reading the RFC, possibly reading and understanding `puff.c`, and looking at examples with `infgen.c`.  Only then can you start to think about ways to create deflate streams with a compressor.

If you are not understanding RFC 1951, then you may need to first study Huffman codes and LZ77 in more depth.

Answer (score 1):

As in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE):

A Deflate stream consists of a series of blocks. Each block is preceded by a 3-bit header, the meaning of the bits are:

First bit: Last-block-in-stream marker:

```
1: this is the last block in the stream.
0: there are more blocks to process after this one.
```

Second and third bits: Encoding method used for this block type:

```
00: a stored/raw/literal section, between 0 and 65,535 bytes in length.
01: a static Huffman compressed block, using a pre-agreed Huffman tree.
10: a compressed block complete with the Huffman table supplied.
11: reserved, don't use.
```

**00     --> LZ77**
**01, 10 --> Huffman**

In case of `LZ77` it's encoded (distance, length) of the repeated string.

In case of `01` Huffman, the Huffman tree is **pre-agreed** (would be hard-coded in the compression and decompression).

In case of `10` Huffman, following is the info for recreate the tree and then the compressed data.